# How to change image mode of WKInterfaceImage programmatically ?(objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, watchkit, wkinterfaceimage

I am developing an app for **watchkit2**. I am setting **image mode** of WKInterfaceImage object from the interface builder to **centre**, I need to change it to **Aspect Fit** after some code is executed.

I cannot see any mention of doing this via code in apple's documentation..
Has anyone encountered this scenario yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 2 instances of your image. Set first's image mode to center, and second's to Aspect Fit. But hide second (hidden flag).
You can show and hide your images with setHidden method

Comment: I am using a WKInterfaceTable, i don't think this approach is optimal for my situation.

Comment: But i might have to use this approach if apple doesn't allow to change mode programatically.

Comment: This remains the only solution in WatchKit 2.